# Check multiple words if exist in array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Have to check if some sentance are writted in an textarea. for ex('Zuzu max capsuni', 'Zuzu Max afine') and so on.

My problem is that I don;t know how to make the function for that. I tried to make an array with those words, and then tried to find them on textarea with indexOf(). 
I didn't succeed to acchieve that, esecially if I write with lower case. Does somebody have a solution? Thanks

```
<div>Button</div>
<textarea></textarea>


var words = ['Zuzu Max capsuni', 'Zuzu max piersici', 'Zuzu Max mere si pere', 'Zuzu Max afine', 'Zuzu Max stracciatella', 'Zuzu max natur'];
var text = $('textarea').val();
$('div').on('click', function(){
    if(text.indexOf(words)){
        console.log('match');
    }
});
```

Forgot to put [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4whgj4m/)

Comment: You are doing ..... `String.indexOf(Array)` ... have to do a loop of array and check each one

Comment: Try using `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` if they are not equal element is repeated

Comment: But how can I check every 3 words or something like that? I will have sentace of 3-5 words, and have to check in this way

Comment: also note you need to get the textarea value inside the click handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through the `words` array and check them one by one against the textarea string. Another problem in your code is that `indexOf` returns `-1` if the string is not found, or a `number` which represents the position of the search string.

```
var textarea = $('textarea');
var words = ['Zuzu Max capsuni', 'Zuzu max piersici', 'Zuzu Max mere si pere', 'Zuzu Max afine', 'Zuzu Max stracciatella', 'Zuzu max natur'];

$('div').on('click', function(){
    var text = textarea.val();

    for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (text.indexOf(words[i]) > -1) {
            console.log('match', words[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

You can see a working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/22vuakp9/

Case insensitive: http://jsfiddle.net/22vuakp9/1/

Comment: It is working ! it makes sense now ! Thanks. Also is there a method to validate the lower case too?

Comment: @codetheweb if you want to make the search case insensitive, just convert the `words` and `text` to lower case. I updated the answer with an updated fiddle.

Comment: Thank you a lot gyo. I tried a day to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that array "word" contains the sentences you want to check
for.

First take all sentences to lowercase or uppercase.You can use UnderscoreJS
for this or you can as well do it yourself.

See below:

```js
var words = ['Zuzu Max capsuni', 'Zuzu max piersici', 'Zuzu Max mere si pere'];

//using underscoreJS . See link: http://underscorejs.org/#map
wordsLowerCase = _.map(words, function(word) {
    return word.toLowerCase();
});


var text = $('textarea').val().toLowerCase();

$('div').on('click', function() {

    wordsLowerCase.forEach(function(word) {
        if (text.indexOf(word) > -1) {
            console.log('match');
        }
    });

});
```

Note: There are several ways you can arrive at your goal. This is just one of those ways.

Which is the best way? It depends.

I hope you find this helpful.

Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

Use lodash or similar library to do so: https://lodash.com/docs#includes

Or if you're comfortable using ES7/Babel: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes